# Net Core: How to Find Configuration Appsettings File Directory being Called while Debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, configuration, startup

From this line of code, how do I find the Configuration (conf) , appsettings file directory its reading from? What is the conf .property which I can use to see its filepath? Trying to Debug, and see which configuration file its reading in Debug Watch window.

**Project Startup.cs**

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    Configuration = configuration;
    HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}

public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    var conf = Configuration;
    IConfiguration appConf = conf.GetSection("ConnectionStrings");
    var connstring = appConf.GetValue<string>("DatabaseConnection");

    services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(a => a.UseSqlServer(connstring));
}
```

**Appsettings.Json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DatabaseConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ApplicationDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on the configuration of your IWebHostBuilder (Program.cs). [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: well I can see the actual text being read from appsettings, I would like to confirm the directory,  isnt their like some config.directory property?

Comment: Do you use the CreateDefaultBuilder? That will set the ContentRootPath to GetCurrentDirectory() (root of your app) and will load IConfigration from appsettings.json and appsettings.[environment].json relative to this path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code to get connection string from appsettings.json file.

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection")));
```